# Samsung smart tv app ID during test?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I've been looking into making an app for samsung smart TVs. I've got the whole development environment up and running, and I also have a 'real' device available for testing. The only thing that I haven't been able to figure out, is how do you get a hold of the appID in development?

I need it because I have to communicate with the TV application. The API to do that is described here: [Client to TV comm](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/javascript_apis/convergence_app_api/convergence_app_client_to_tvapp_comm.html)

The docs say:

> Note: appID is an unique TV application ID issued by Samsung Apps.

Does that mean that the ID is only assigned once the app has been uploaded to the Samsung 'App Store'? If so, how can I test the communication between my client and TV app before uploading it?

Comment: The appId is the value of curWidget.id

Comment: If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appId is the value of curWidget.id, for example:

```
var appId = curWidget.id;
```